# Force jlrs to use newer bindgen?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use the jlrs crate (v0.6),

- which depends on  jl-sys version 0.8,
- which depends on bindgen version 0.54.1,
- which is yanked.

When I run `cargo update` it says:

```
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `bindgen = "^0.54.1"`
  candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.55.1, 0.55.0, 0.54.0, ...
  location searched: crates.io index
required by package `jl-sys v0.8.0`
    ... which is depended on by `jlrs v0.6.0`
```

So far as I can see, [jl-sys](https://github.com/Taaitaaiger/jlrs/blob/master/jl_sys/Cargo.toml) requires exactly bindgen version 0.54.1, which has been [yanked](https://crates.io/crates/bindgen/0.54.1).   Is there an easy way to persuade it to use a newer version?

Comment: *"So far as I can see, jl-sys requires exactly bindgen version 0.54.1"* -- no, `^0.54.1` allows any version equal to or greater than `0.54.1`, but less than `0.55.0`. (See [Caret requirements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#caret-requirements) for why that is) Unfortunately for you, the next version of the crate after the yanked `0.54.1` is `0.55.0`, which is outside that range.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but [the `[patch]` section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#the-patch-section) might be something you could use.

Comment: In the meantime, I've [submitted an issue](https://github.com/Taaitaaiger/jlrs/issues/14) about the broken dependency and it looks like the crate owner should be fixing it soon.

Answer (score 1):

@Herotar was right about the [[patch]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#the-patch-section) section being what I needed.

First I checked out https://github.com/Taaitaaiger/jlrs which contains the `jl-sys` source.  Then I bumped the version of bindgen referenced in `jl-sys` to 0.55

Modified my `Cargo.toml` like this

```
[dependencies]
jlrs = "0.6"
jl-sys = "0.8.0"

[patch.crates-io]
jl-sys = { path = '/home/me/jlrs/jl_sys' }
```

Then it all worked.